# Laravel query LeftJoin show all categories even in right table have not that category

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two table following:

```
tb_category

id  |name      |
----------------
1   |Category A|
2   |Category B|
3   |Category C|
4   |Category D|
5   |Category E|

tb_sales
id |customer   |region       |product       |category
-------------------------------------------------------
1   James       Region A      Fruits         Category A
2   Billy       Region B      Vegetable      Category B
3   Benny       Region C      Computer       Category C
4   John        Region A      Table          Category D
5   Sarah       Region B      Fruits         Category A
6   James       Region A      Computer       Category C
7   Clara       Region B      Fruits         Category A
8   Benny       Region C      Vegetable      Category B
9   James       Region A      Vegetable      Category B
10  Billy       Region C      Fruits         Category A
```

I would like to create query and result a table like table below
where all category count and show even in tb_sales have not category.

```
No  |name           |Region A   |Region B   |Region C
-----------------------------------------------------
1   Category A         1          1           1
2   Category B         1          1           1
3   Category C         1          0           1
4   Category D         1          0           0
5   Category E         0          0           0
```

```
in my controller I have write like this:

            $cat = DB::table('tb_sales')
                ->leftJoin('tb_category','tb_category.name', '=', 'tb_sales.category')
                ->select(DB::raw('category, region, count(category) as c_Cat'))
                ->groupBy('category', 'region')
                ->get();

                return view('category', ['Category'=> $cat]);
```

Could anyone help my this problem..?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the error of your current query ?

Comment: It's not error but not show all category that only show category in tb_sales, I want to show and count all category form tb_category even in tb_sales have not category (zero value).

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has solved with answer from laracast @Tray2. Thanks @Tray2.

use this query:

```
SELECT c.name, 
         (SELECT count(s.*) from tb_sales s WHERE category = c.name AND s.region = 'Region A') AS region_a,
         (SELECT count(s.*) from tb_sales s WHERE category = c.name AND s.region = 'Region B') AS region_b,
             (SELECT count(s.*) from tb_sales s WHERE category = c.name AND s.region = 'Region C') AS region_c
FROM tb_category c
ORDER by c.name ASC
```

and passing that query to controller:

```
$result = DB::select(<the query here>);
```

I hope this can help someone with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you use left join from tb_sales to category wherein you want to retrieve all category together with it's region. Try this code below

```
 $cat = DB::table('tb_category')
                ->leftJoin('tb_sales','tb_category.name', '=', 'tb_sales.category')
                ->select(DB::raw('category, region, count(category) as c_Cat'))
                ->groupBy('category', 'region')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually the result from your code its not different with my code above (result from dd($cat) show repeat category) I want to don't show repeat category. Could you show me how to showing result table like my question above? where the category name in column 2 and region A, B, C to next column.